# Car misfiring after oil change and engine wash

Tags: oil-change

My car oil was changed yesterday then he washed motor and was revving engine a lot because it was misfiring badly.Is it because of fresh oil change or some part got wet? I really appreciate your opinions ..ba 2005 xr6

Comment: Was it still missing once you got it home?

Comment: Doubtful the oil change, per se, would have anything to do with this.  Wet ignition wires are almost always suspect.

Comment: If the misfire hasn't been introduced by moisture getting into the electrical system of the vehicle I'd be very surprised.